# "It was raining"/"It rained"

Tags: past-tense

So I've been learning English for three years now and I really love the language. But the further you get into the language, the more complex it gets and I often find myself confused by all those tenses. In my english book there was a sentence "**It rained** every day of our holiday" and I was wondering if you could also say "**It was raining** every day of our holiday."
If not, could you please tell me why?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could, and it would have a slightly different meaning (or rather, different emphasis).

"It rained every day" means that at some point each day it rained. Given that this is mentioned in the narrative, you can probably assume that it was raining at the relevant times every day; but it doesn't explicitly say that.

"It was raining every day" implies that at some relevant time each day (perhaps the time they wanted to go out) it was raining.

As usual with aspectual differences, it does not necessarily mean a difference in the objective events, but in how the speaker is choosing to view them.